# Выборка из базы с заменой значения колонки MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю запрос в БД. Задача стоит следующая: делаю выборку из таблицы A, в которой есть колонки price_min, price_max, weight_min, weight_max. В случае, если значений в полях не стоит, то при SELECT'е нужно подставлять значения из таблицы B, которая состоит с таблицей A в отношениях один ко многим A1 - nB. В таблице B есть колонки price, weight и A_id.

В результате, если нет какой-то какое-то из полей таблицы А не заполнено, я должен получить в это поле минимальное/максимальное значение аналогичной колонки из таблицы B, а саму таблицу А обновлять при этом нельзя.

Я выделывал запрос вида: SELECT *, (SELECT MIN(price) FROM B WHERE A.id = B.A_id) as price_min, (тут другие min/max выборки такого же вида) FROM A LEFT/RIGHT/INNER (пробовал эти на разных этапах) JOIN B ON B.A_id = A.id GROUP BY A.id
(запрос примерный, писал по памяти)

В итоге я то значения получал, но они подставлялись соответственно в колонки price_min1, price_max1 и так далее.
Как сделать подстановку значения именно внутрь существующей колонки.

Можно проигнорировать условие, что выборку надо делать только если значений не проставлено (там и так должны быть максимальные/минимальные значения с соответствующими наименованиями, но так как они есть не везде, то я подумал что было бы логично не менять их, если они уже стоят)

Comment: никогда не пишите `*`, явно перечисляйте требуемые колонки. а дальше все становится просто, в списке колонок вместо price_min пишите формулу, т.е. `coalesce(price_min, (select min() ...)) as price_min` (хотя конечно запрос с left join и group by может быть оптимальнее в случае если пустых price_min в первой таблице много)

Comment: Вообще красавчик, то что нужно. * я написал, чтобы не перечислять здесь, в коде все четко перечислено, спасибо. Тут есть как на mail.ru пометка, типа что ответ топовый?